# An NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: python, django

I know that NoReverseMatch problem means something wrong with my URLs, but I just could not find where the problem is

views.py:

```
def edit(request,post_id):
e = Note.objects.get(id=post_id)
form = Edit()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Edit(request.POST.copy())
    if form.is_valid():
        data1 = form.cleaned_data
        g = Note.objects.get(id=post_id)
        g.title = data1['title']
        g.content = data1['content']
        g.category = data1['category']
        g.subject_name = data1['subject_name']
        g.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/notebook/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Not good')
else:
    form = Edit(initial={'title': e.title,'content': e.content, 'category' : e.category,
                         'subject_name': e.subject_name})
return render(request,'notebook/edit.html',{'form': form})
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
url(r'^/post/$', views.post, name='post'),
url(r'^category(?P<category>\w+)/$', views.show_category, name='show_category'),
url(r'^subject(?P<id>\w+)/$', views.show_subject, name='show_subject'),
url(r'^/create_subject/$', views.create_subject, name='create_subject'),
# url(r'/upload_image/$', views.upload_image, name='upload_image'),
]
```

The Error:

```
Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notebook/edit/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

And by the way, I have to say this, which I think is important, before I added the class Subject, which means the form had nothing to do with it in the first place, the function edit() worked just fine.
And besides, parts of my form looks like this:

```
class Edit(forms.Form):

title = forms.CharField(label=('title')
content = forms.CharField(label=('content'),widget=forms.Textarea)
category = forms.CharField(label=('category')
subject_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.all())
```

Comment: You need to show the part of your template that is trying to access the `edit` url

Comment: As an aside, you should remove the leading slash from your regexes, it should be `r'^post/$'` and `r'^create_subject/$'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using a url filter tag in your template. You need to pass the post_id as a parameter in your url filter tag.

```
{%  url 'edit' post_id %}
```

On a side note, you should preferably use reverse or reverse_lazy to get url's rather than hard coding them

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name'))
```

Comment: You also have to pass `post_id` to the template context i.e. `{'form': form, 'post_id': post_id}`.

Comment: Yeah it works so great! Thanks you guys.  But what I can understand is, why it could still work in the first place? I barely changed it at all.